# HTTP.get not providing data in time

Tags: javascript, meteor, request

I'm trying to display the users location with the help of ipinfo.io. I created a meteor server method:

```
 ipLocate: function() {
      HTTP.get("http://ipinfo.io", function(error, result) {
        var place = JSON.parse(result.content);
        city = place.city;
        state = place.region;
      });
        return [city,state];
    }
```

Which returns the city and state of the user (but only on the second time it's executed).

I made a global helper

```
Template.registerHelper('locationFull', function() {

      // if (!Meteor.userId()) {

      Meteor.call('ipLocate', function(error, result) {
        response = result
        Session.set('location', response);
      })
      return Session.get('location');
}
```

Which currently displays nothing.

If I manually run the HTTP.get request (from my ipLocate method) in the client, it returns the city and state but only after I run it twice.

How can I get the city and state to be returned in my global helper on page load.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up putting my HTTP call in a `Template.onCreated()` and returned the variable set with a Session var within the global helper.

Like:

```
 Template.registerHelper('locationFull', function() {
    return Session.get('locate');
  });
```

This worked.

Answer (score 1):

This is because you're running the request asynchronously.  Since your return code is outside of your `HTTP.get` callback (and it needs to be, it would throw an error otherwise), there is no value.  The reason it returns a value on the second time is because you declared city and state as global variables (no `var` qualifier in front of them).  The proper way to do this is to store the data you get back in a Mongo collection that is published to the client template.  Checkout the [Meteor Guide](http://guide.meteor.com) if you don't know how to store and publish data.

Comment: Could I store the data in any other way besides using mongo? I'm working on the pre-authenticated part of my app where the user has not logged in yet.